# react download the document in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am trying to download the file on the same page. But the problem is not happening.

I debugged the code, getting the data in b64Data variable. url is adding in blobUrl, but I need to download in the same page similar to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/7NqKb/

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Providing my code snippet below:

```or-tag-here
fileContents = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("data.content--->", data.data.content);
        var contentType = 'application/pdf';

        var b64Data = data.data.content;

        var blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log("displayDocumentData blobUrl--->", blobUrl);
        //window.location = blobUrl;
        console.log(blobUrl);
        this.setState({ downloadUrl: blobUrl });


    }


    <Button
    onClick={e => {
        this.props.actions.downloadDocumentData(this.fileContents);
    }}
    variant="outlined"
    color="primary"
    size="small"
// className={classes.button}
>

    Download Document test
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');
link.setAttribute('download', 'your file name');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: hey its working, can you tell me how to achieve in react way...and can you explain about your code

Comment: this code creates an invisible <a/> html element that links to your resource, and programmatically clicks it to make the download start